# In R, how can I reference an S4 class from another package in my class definition?

Tags: r, package, r-s4

Suppose I have two packages `PackageA` and `PackageB`. I have an S4 class, `ClassA`, in `PackageA` that I would like to use as a base class for `ClassB` in `PackageB`:

```
setClass(
    "ClassB", 
    slots = c(), 
    validity = function(object) {

        T
    }
    contains = "ClassA")
```

However, when I build I get the error:

> no definition found for superclass "ClassA"

I have tried adding a reference to the `PackageA` with `devtools`:

```
devtools::use_package("PackageA")
```

Perhaps I need to use an `roxygen` directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that `ClassA` was not being imported properly. Adding the correct `roxygen` directive solved the problem:

```
#' @import PackageA
setClass(
    "ClassB", 
    slots = c(), 
    validity = function(object) {

        T
    }
    contains = "ClassA")
```